# pandas.DataFrame and pandas.Series objects act differently for pandas.get_dummies()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a `dataframe` by the name train with a column 'quality'.

```
>>>train['quality'].unique()
array([5, 6, 7, 4, 8, 3], dtype=int64)
```

Now `get_dummies` with `train[['quality']]` gives

```
>>>pd.get_dummies(train[['quality']]).head()

    quality
0   5
1   5
2   5
3   6
4   5
```

but with `train['quality']`

```
>>>pd.get_dummies(train['quality']).head()

    3   4   5   6   7   8
0   0   0   1   0   0   0
1   0   0   1   0   0   0
2   0   0   1   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   1   0   0
4   0   0   1   0   0   0
```

Data Types of `train[['quality']]` and `train['quality']` are:-

```
>>>print(type(train['quality']))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>>print(type(train[['quality']]))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

the `get_dummies()` doc states: `data : array-like, Series, or DataFrame`

So if I can give in both a Series or  `DataFrame` then why are the outputs different?

Comment: The docs say that `get_dummies` accepts both dataframes and series. It does **not** say that the returned object type or shape is the same in both cases

Comment: How does `get_dummies()` serve its purpose in case of `train[['quality']]` since I didn't get back my OneHot dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`pd.get_dummies` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) makes this pretty clear:

> `columns` : list-like, default `None`
>   Column names in the DataFrame to be 
>   encoded. If columns is None then all the columns with object or
>   category dtype will be converted.

So, the solution is to either specify a `columns` parameter, thus overriding the requirement for the column to be categorical/object type to begin with,

```
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['quality'])

   quality_5  quality_6
0          1          0
1          1          0
2          1          0
3          0          1
4          1          0
```

Or, convert the column to categorical.

```
pd.get_dummies(df[['quality']].astype('category'))

   quality_5  quality_6
0          1          0
1          1          0
2          1          0
3          0          1
4          1          0
```

Comment: can you please explain a bit more, i am trying to understand the difference.

Comment: @RishiBansal What exactly are you confused with?

Answer (score 0):

Data needs to be converted to categorical types for get_dummies to work. If a series is passed in, the conversion occurs automatically. As outlined in the documentation and by coldspeed, if a DataFrame is passed in, all object or category dtypes (series of these datatypes) are converted to categorical and will result in dummy columns. For example:

```
pandas.get_dummies(pandas.DataFrame(list("abcdabcd"))) 

   0_a  0_b  0_c  0_d
0    1    0    0    0
1    0    1    0    0
2    0    0    1    0
3    0    0    0    1
4    1    0    0    0
5    0    1    0    0
6    0    0    1    0
7    0    0    0    1
```

This works because the list of strings becomes a column of strings which are objects.

Perhaps a bit unintuitively, your integer-type column is not of type "object" and thus is not converted into categorical, so dummy columns are not returned and the original DataFrame is returned. Numerical types in pandas are distinct from objects. You can work around this by simply passing df[["quality"]].astype("category") since this will force the conversion of your integer column to categorical which will then return dummy columns.

EDIT: To expand a bit, one has to keep in mind that dummy variables are a construct for regression (or extensions of regression). If a Dataframe contains dtypes that are both numeric and objects, more often than not, the numeric types are intended to be used directly as inputs for the model. However, object types have no value in regression unless converted to dummy variables. Thus if someone were to pass to get_dummies a DataFrame with three numeric types and one object type, the one object type would be converted to a dummy variable. *This is only the default behaviour if the columns parameter is left unspecified*. The columns parameter exists in the case that the default behaviour does not suit your needs e.g. you do not want all object/categorical dtype columns converted, or you want a column of numeric dtype converted.